# How to change the ownership of a table in database

Tags: database, postgresql

I Have a database rndb and created a new table myname_record which is created with owner "postgres" by default. In my program i should have change the owner to "rndb" but i missed it. Now i need to do it in console so i am login with command

```
psql=>psql -Urndb
```

and then changing the owner with following query

```
rndb=>ALTER TABLE public.myname_record OWNER to rndb;
```

but it is saying you must be owner to do this changes. I can understood because i am login through rndb it is giving this error. But how to make this changes actually.

Comment: You can check if both users have same grant?  try to run `grant postgres to rndb;` and check if your flow works without any changes to table ownership.

Answer (score 120):

Select a role with superuser permission and try to change the owner of your table.

```
ALTER TABLE public.myname_record OWNER TO rndb;
```

Answer (score 7):

You must connect as the *current* table owner, not the user you wish to change the table ownership to. Since that's `postgres`:

```
psql -U postgres
```

or

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

as required.

(Also, a superuser can always change table ownerships from anything to anything).

Comment: when i am doing the same it is saying:- relation "public.myname_record" does not exist